# Generating multiple xlswrite outputs separately

Tags: matlab

I am having some trouble generating xlswrite outputs separately.

I have a loop that goes

```
   for g = 1:3
```

In side this loop, for every loop, I want to creata a separate xlsx file.

I tried

```
xlswrite('test_' g '.xlsx',[1 3])
```

and

```
xlswrite(['test_' g '.xlsx'],[1 3])
```

But neither worked.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the numeric value of `g` into a string, so either

```
xlswrite(['test_',num2str(g),'.xlsx'],[1 3]);
```

or

```
xlswrite(sprintf('test_%d.xlsx',g),[1 3]);
```

Comment: @Phil_Goddard Thank you very much!